# django form validation error not showing in DetailView

Tags: python, django

What am i trying to do is show comment form in Detailview.
it can add comment, but when user write noting in the form it doesn't show error message.
I think i need to return error form somehow, i can not find how
this is my code

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    comment_text = forms.CharField(max_length=300,
        error_messages={'required':'need comment!!!'},
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields= ('comment_text',)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_comment(request, pk):
    parent_photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.parent_photo = parent_photo
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect(parent_photo.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            @@@@@@@@   this part???  @@@@@@@@
            return redirect(parent_photo.get_absolute_url(), {'comment_form': form })

    return redirect(parent_photo.get_absolute_url())

class PhotoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Photo
    template_name = 'photo_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        object = self.get_object()
        
        total_likes =  object.total_likes()
        
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm
        context['total_likes'] = total_likes
        return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', views.PhotoDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/add_comment/', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
]
```

templates

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated%}
            <div class=" my-3">
                <p class='mb-0 ml-2'>Leave a comment ! </p>
                <form class="input-group" id='comment_form' method="POST"
                    action="{{ photo.get_absolute_url }}add_comment/">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in comment_form %}
                    <input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
                        name="{{ field.name }}">
                    {% if field.errors %}
                        <small class='text-danger'>{{ field.errors }}</samll>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">ADD</button>
                    </div>
                    {%endfor%}
                </form>
            </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can not pass values when you redirect. A redirect is simply a response that says "fetch the page located ....", and thus that view starts over again.

Answer (score 0):

i put 'required' in input

```
<input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
                        name="{{ field.name }}">
```

and in add_comment view, only consider is_valid() case.

```
@login_required
def add_comment(request, pk):
    parent_photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.parent_photo = parent_photo
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect(parent_photo.get_absolute_url())
            
    return redirect(parent_photo.get_absolute_url())
```

it is not the answer for my question,
but works as i intended.